# Laravel Image validation only accepting .png files

Tags: php, laravel

I have added a form added image file upload and validated it, the file upload accepting only `.png` file. When I choose `jpg,jpeg` or other formats throws error message field must be an image.

**Laravel version Version 5.8.38**

**My controller Method**

```
 public function store() {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required | image'
        ]);

        Post::create($data); 
 }
```

**My View**

```
<form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
@csrf
<div class="row">
<label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Image</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

@error('image')
<strong style="color: #e3342f;font-size:80%">{{ $message }}</strong>
@enderror
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use mimes in validation    "mimes:jpeg,bmp,png"

Comment: what the laravel version you are using?

Comment: I have added on Description

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store() {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
        ]);

        Post::create($data); 
 }
```

Comment: use must use  mimes: png @UshaniKulathilaka   top code for sample

Comment: Laravel documentation says, if we use `image`  in  validation all image formats are accepted. But its not working as so ,only accepting `.png`

Comment: use 'image' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png' @UshaniKulathilaka

Comment: Still the same problem, only `png`  working

Comment: it's work for me , the problem another thing

Comment: Laravel version Version 5.8.38

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. This happens because the list of valid mimes specified by Laravel only includes "jpeg" but the mime guesser guesses the file type as "jpg". Since the image validation just appears to be a shorthand for validating the mime types, you can specify these yourself and add "jpeg". The following is functionality equivalent to the `image` validator but without the bug:

```
mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,bmp,svg
```

It's important to leave out the `image` requirement. No need to specify `file` either since that's done by the mime validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
"image"=>'image | required | mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg | max:2048',
```

in your cause you can choose `mimes: png`

Comment: try use formRequest instead of validate

Comment: Yes, I tried, still the same issue, Only accepting `PNG`

Comment: up your project on git and share  it's link

Comment: Its my company project cannot share public